# Don't know where to start with multiple queries

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

Please apologize my English.

I need some orientation, I need to do this:

Make a query to MYSQL from PHP to pick some rows, and then make another query with every result.

So I've wrote this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE `comprador` = '$comprador' AND `estado` = 'cart'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    /* array asociativo */
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

 $id = $row['id'];
 $delivery = $row['delivery'];

 if($delivery =='ZICHER'){ $status = 'Pagado';} else if($delivery =='USUARIO'){ $status = 'Por Cobrar';}

 $query = "UPDATE pedidos SET estado='$status' WHERE comprador='$comprador'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    }
```

But this lines dont respect the ***if*** condition, and set all rows from pedidos to exactly the same $status.

So them I've added this condition to the second query:

WHERE id='$id' <<--- but this just only change de first result.

Just need some orientation, thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. add `where id=$id` back to query 2. replace `$result = $mysqli->query($query);` with `$mysqli->query($query);`

Comment: It worked perfectly, can you please explain that to me?

Comment: variable `$result` contains result of first query, so you should not overwrite it

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need really multiple queries for this. You can just use the WHERE condition from your first query in the update query, and an [IF function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to set the appropriate value.

```
$sql = "UPDATE pedidos
SET estado = IF(delivery='ZICHER', 'Pagado', 'Por Cobrar')
WHERE comprador='$comprador'
AND estado = 'cart'";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

I know this doesn't explain the problem with your current code, but it looks like you got that in the comments already.

Comment: Hi! great alternative, I think this could work faster.

Comment: Probably so. Generally the fewer queries you have to execute, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
echo print_r($result, true);
```

to see the returned result and change

```
$delivery = $row['delivery'];
```

accordingly. Perhaps you need to write something like :

```
$delivery = $row[0]['delivery'];
```

Comment: I've solved my problem, thanks a lot for helping me :)